# TSQL change column constraint between null and not null

Tags: sql-server, null

I am doing a exercise to change a column's constraint between null to not null. 
Table name: `Production.categoriesTest`. Please review my question and give me suggestion
on what I did wrong and how to fix the issue. Thanks!

1. when table was created, the `description` column is set to `NOT NULL`
2. I used the update clause to set `description` column to `NULL`
3. When using alter table command to set the column `description` back to `NOT NULL`, I received an error message.

Error message:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 98
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'description', table 'TSQL2012.Production.categoriesTest'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

Create table command:

```
 create table Production.categoriesTest
    categoryid INT not null identity,
    categoryname nvarchar(15) not null,
    description nvarchar(200) not null,
    constraint PK_Categories1 Primary Key (categoryid)

--update clause make all description column becomes 'NULL"
  update Production.categoriesTest
  set description = NULL
  where categoryid = 8;
```

The description column became 'NULL'

I did insert a value for description column in the able after the column set to Null.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense as written because you have created a column declared as `NOT NULL` and immediately try to update the same field to `NULL`. Of course it fails. What you haven't done is to  is to issue an `ALTER TABLE` command like so: `ALTER TABLE Production.categoriesTest ALTER COLUMN description NVARCHAR(200) NULL` to make the column `NULL`able. An `UPDATE` statement cannot alter the definition, only the data and it is bound by the constraint.

Answer (score 3):

When trying to return the column back to `NOT NULL` SQL Server immediately checks the constraint, which fails because the rows for that column were set to `NULL`.

For an existing column, you have to update the table to remove any `NULL` values before you can set it as `NOT NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply AlwaysLoadingData and Steve. I used update clause to set each row to a value that is not null. I was able to update the column constraint back to 'NOT NULL'